# Git Doesn't Show All Branches

Tags: git, gitlab

My co-developer made a lot of changes on his remote gitlab repository: merged, deleted, created new branches etc.

Now I need to work on a new feature branch that he's just created. I open my Gitbash, do:

```
git pull git@gitlab.example.com:root/project-name.git
git checkout new-feature
```

I get `error: pathspec 'new-feature' didn't match any file(s) known to git.`

Then I tried:

```
git show-ref
```

This only shows two branches, while it should show at least 8.
I also tried fetch which made no difference whatsoever.

Are the files really missing or is it simply not tracking the new branches?
How do I get the new branch to my local workspace?
Would `git clone` solve it or only make it worse? Thanks.

UPDATE: Thank you for your help, unfortunately, neither of the suggestions worked and I had to delete everything, set it up from scratch and do a fresh git clone. We looked through the error logs but didn't find any clues. Just one of those things, I guess.

Comment: Have you asked your co-worker if he pushed his new branch to the `origin`? If so, have you tried `git pull origin new-feature`?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` tell you?

Comment: `git pull git@gitlab.example.com:root/project-name.git` - does that even work?

Comment: Matt McNabb, yeah, why wouldn't it? That's how I got the files last time. Does it look wrong?

Comment: Jubobs, same as `git show-ref` - i.e. I've got 2 branches, not 8.

Comment: NuclearPeon, can't ask him, he's gone unresponsive. If I try your suggestion, I get: fatal: `origin does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: *[...] while it should show at least 8.* What makes you think that? If your coworker deleted branches and you then pulled from the remote, those branches will have ceased to exist in your local repo also. It looks like the remote doesn't have any branch called `new-feature`, if it ever had one.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I just stumbled over it because I had the same problem. After checking 'man git' I found out that 'git fetch' does the trick. So, for anyone who might come across this topic in the future:

1. Go to a terminal.
2. Navigate to the project directory.
3. Enter `git fetch`.

As the description of `git fetch` states:

> Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their histories. Remote-tracking
>          branches are updated (see the description of  below for ways to control this behavior).

Comment: Thanks!! This comment helped me today. Old thread or not, it was still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the branch on remote

```
git checkout origin/branch-name
```

Also, we use network graph in gitlab UI heavily to check any inconsistencies with the branch.

Comment: Thanks, when I do this, I get the same pathspec error as before. Just logged in to check his gitlab dashboard and the Network section looks logical. I can see all 8 branches. Still I can only access two on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to the repository first:

```
git remote add somerepo git@gitlab.example.com:root/project-name.git
```

Then when you do a pull git will store the remote tracking branches in somerepo/new-feature, and when you do `git checkout new-feature` it will create a new local branch based on that.

When you do `git pull <url>` only the HEAD is fetched, and it's stored in FETCH_HEAD, which is probably not what you want.